# Design or Class/Component-hierarchy to be followed for the wizard application

Tags: java, swing, wizard

I'm Java Begginner. Below shown is the wizard which I want to achieve.

[image]

For this, Do I need to create my customized hierarchy of components ? like...

```
JFrame > JpanelMain. 
JpanelMain > Banner panel.
JpanelMain > LH Navigation panel.
JpanelMain > Bottom panel with buttons...
```

I tried using Netbeans to create wizard modules using Tutorial (http://platform.netbeans.org/tutorials/nbm-wizard.html). Here explaination is about creating Netbeans Dialoug wizards, which run in Netbeans. But What I'm searching is how to make a standalone application showing as wizard (similar to some installers).

Can somebody tell me, what design or implementation need to be followed?

Are there any available wizards libraries(with proper documentation) to assist in creating wizards? (Found some libraries in internet, but not sure how to use them, bec of not proper documentation.)

OR do i need to follow creating customized hierarchy of swing components? If yes, what design/implementation need to be followed?

Comment: I am working on a similar project, and I found [this article](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/GUI/swing/wizard/) useful to make certain design decisions.

Answer (score 0):

You could try checking out

http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-04-2008/jw-04-opensourcejava-wizard-api.html

Haven't used personally.

I think the SwingX (Swing-Labs) project also has one