# programmatically close a JPanel which is displayed in JDialog

Tags: java, swing

I have a main application frame (`MainFrame class`). On actionperformed event of a `JButton`, a  `JPanel (MyJPanel class)` is opened by placing it in `JDialog`. I am not extending `JDialog` to create `MyJPanel` class because I might need MyJPanel at other purposes too.

My Problem is I cannot programmatically close the `MyJPanel` which is displayed in `JDialog`. Is there anything that I missing? Could you please figure it out?

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;


    public class MainFrame extends JPanel {
        public MainFrame() {

            JButton btnOpenJdialog = new JButton("Open JDialog");
            add(btnOpenJdialog);
            btnOpenJdialog.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    JDialog jd = new JDialog();
                    MyJPanel mjp = new MyJPanel(true);//showing in JDialog
                    jd.setTitle("JDialog");
                    jd.add(mjp);
                    jd.pack();
                    jd.setVisible(true);

                }
            });
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

                public void run() {
                    createAndShowGUI();
                }
            });
        }

        public static void createAndShowGUI() {

            JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test-JFrame");
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.getContentPane().add(new MainFrame());
            frame.pack();
            frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            frame.setVisible(true);
        }

    }
```

MyJPanel Class :

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JButton;

public class MyJPanel extends JPanel {
    private boolean isShownInJDialog = false;

    public MyJPanel() {
        JButton btnCloseMe = new JButton("Finish Action");
        add(btnCloseMe);
        btnCloseMe.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (isShownInJDialog) {
                    MyJPanel.this.setVisible(false);
                    //how to close the JDialog too.
                }
                else {
                    //just hide the content, 
                    MyJPanel.this.setVisible(false);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public MyJPanel(boolean isShownInJDialog) {
        this();
        this.isShownInJDialog = isShownInJDialog;

    }

}
```

**UPDATE**
I was able to solve this using Howard's answer as :

```
...     
if (isShownInJDialog) {
        Window w = SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(MyJPanel.this);
        w.setVisible(false);
}
...
```

Comment: By 'close the panel' DYM 'close the dialog'?  Panels themselves are either shown or hidden, perhaps swapped in a `CardLayout`.

Comment: [please to read this thread, especially comment by @missingfaktor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10933968/design-or-class-component-hierarchy-to-be-followed-for-the-wizard-application)

Comment: @AndrewThompson, I have modified my code, Actually there will be a `Boolean` to decide if `MyJPanel` is currently showing in `JDialog` (or anything that extends `Window`) or in another `Container`. I am able to solve this by the help of Howard's answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to close the `JDialog` which your `MyJPanel` is contained in but do not have a reference to it?

You may either provide such a reference using the constructor of `MyJPanel` or change the code inside your `ActionListener` to

```
Window w = SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(MyJPanel.this);
w.setVisible(false);
```

which looks up the parent window of your panel without direct reference.

Comment: *"I might need MyJPanel at other purposes too"*  If one of those purposes involves displaying it in the main app., that code snippet would close the app. (or at least set it not visible).

Comment: @AndrewThompson But you shouldn't name it `Close Me` then. So technically you are right - but if you want different logic for different purposes you have to implement it anyways.

Comment: @AndrewThompson, Howard, I have modified my code, Actually there will be a `Boolean` to decide if `MyJPanel` is currently showing in `JDialog` (or anything that extends `Window`) or in another `Container`. I am able to solve this by the help of Howard's answer. Thanks Howard.