# How to update values of a JFrame main after using a JDialog of Java Swing?

Tags: java, swing

I have a main window called MainFrame which is a jForm to which I update the data depending on a timer, but the problem is that I cannot update the data in the same MainFrame after using the jdialog, since I end up creating another duplicate window, but with the data changed, one with the original timer and the other with the new timer, I know that I can close the first window with dispose() and then keep the second, but I would like to avoid changing windows so much

the code with which I create another window when pressing the jDialog button is the following

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {//GEN-FIRST:event_jButton1ActionPerformed
        // TODO add your handling code here:

        String textoFieldTimer = jTextField1.getText();

        int timeUserConfig = Integer.parseInt(textoFieldTimer);
        
        Timer timeDefault = new Timer(timeUserConfig, null);
        
        TokenAccess token = new TokenAccess();
        token.access_code = code;

        MainFrame mainFrame = new MainFrame(token);
        mainFrame.setVisible(true);

        mainFrame.timeDefault.stop();
        mainFrame.timeDefault = timeDefault;
        
        mainFrame.setUpdateTime(timeUserConfig);
        this.dispose();

    }//GEN-LAST:event_jButton1ActionPerformed
```

Is there any alternative to update the window? something like `mainFrame.update();` or maybe send the value of the jTextField from the jDialog to mainFrame? since the previous code creates another MainFrame for me.

Method main setLabel and Timer.start/stop

```
public void setUpdateTime(int timeUserConfig) {
        this.timeUserConfig = timeUserConfig;
        if (timeUserConfig == 0) {
            timeDefault.start();
            timeDefault.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                    setLabelText();
                    String timeUserConfigStr = Integer.toString(timeDefaultInt);
                    tiempoActualizado.setText("Tiempo de Actualizado: " + timeUserConfigStr+"ms");
                }
            });
        } else {          
            timeDefault.stop();
            timeDefault = new Timer(timeUserConfig, null);
            timeDefault.start();
            timeDefault.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                    setLabelText();
                    String timeUserConfigStr = Integer.toString(timeUserConfig);
                    tiempoActualizado.setText("Tiempo de Actualizado: " + timeUserConfigStr+"ms");
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

setLabelText is a method set of label

```
public void setLabelText() {

        String humedadStr = String.valueOf(humedad);
        String temperaturaStr = String.valueOf(temperatura);
        String presionStr = String.valueOf(co2);

        temporalHum.setText(humedadStr);
        temporalTemperatura.setText(temperaturaStr);
        temporalPresion.setText(presionStr);
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include your source code as a working [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others.

Comment: If you don't want to create a new duplicate window, why do you create a duplicate window?

Comment: @Progman I added little since in netbeans many lines of code are created with the interfaces, and since I'm just trying to find a different solution or path with respect to the code I put, I didn't see it as necessary, but I'll do it, basically it's a main window with a button display a jdialog and pass that variable to the main window. there lies more or less the problem, I have looked for solutions but I don't know how I could do it without creating a new window

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the update, and I found another solution without using an `OptionPane` from this question: [programmatically close a JPanel which is displayed in JDialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10936306/programmatically-close-a-jpanel-which-is-displayed-in-jdialog).

I cannot replicate your codings

Start with the `MainFrame`, assuming you opened the `JDialog` by clicking on a button and wants to `setText()` to label `lbSomething`:

```
private void btInputActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    // Open new JDialog when button is clicked
    NewJDialog dialog = new NewJDialog(new javax.swing.JFrame, true);
    dialog.setVisible(true);
    // Get user input from JDialog
    String temp = dialog.getInput();
    if (temp != null) {
        /*
         * Perform jButton1ActionPerformed() content here
         * Including timeUserConfig, timeDefault and setUpdateTime() here
         * so that you don't have to access mainFrame in the JDialog.
        */
        lbSomething.setText(temp);
    }
}
```

Then about the `JDialog` (with simple input detection):

```
public class NewJDialog extends javax.swing.JDialog {

    // Set the variable as class variable
    private String textTOFieldTimer;

    public NewJDialog(java.awt.Frame parent, boolean modal) {
        // default contents
    }

    @SupressWarinings("unchecked")
    private void initComponents() {
        // default contents
    }

    private void btSaveAction Performed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        // Check if input correct and whether to disable JDialog
        if (tfInput.getText.length() != 0) {
            input = tfInput.getText();
            // Connect to the whole JDialog by getWindowAncestor()
            Window window = SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(NewJDialog.this);
            // Just setVisible(false) instead of dispose()
            window.setVisible(false);
        } else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Wrong Input");
        }
    }

    public String getInput() {
        return textToFieldTimer;
    }

    // default variables declarations
}
```

Hope this answer helps you well.

---

Would be better if you displayed the source code, but a simple solution to update values to an existing JFrame is by using `setText()` and `getText()`.

For example:

```
String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(this, "Nuevo valor");
lbPresionActual.setText(input);
```

If you created a self-defined `JDialog`, it is about to transfer the `input` value when closing the `JDialog`, and that could be a different question.

Comment: thanks for the answer, I added more code, but how can I send the variable of the textfield/input to the main window without having to create it again, keeping the one that is present

Comment: I just saw what you changed, I'm going to try Make a jOptionPane

Comment: I updated the answer, hope it would better solve your doubt.

Comment: I decided to create a joptionpane similar to the one you placed and adapted it to my situation, I would still like to create my own joptionpane to be able to design it, so I'm working on it now, but what you said works, thank you very much

Comment: You're welcome, and this is actually a really good question. I detailed the contents in the `JDialog`, perhaps it can give more insight to you. Hope you work well on the project :)